# connect to Oracle with cx_Oracle with secured password

Tags: python-2.7, oracle11g, windows-server-2012, cx-oracle

Currently, I am connecting to Oracle using a string like this:

```
OracleURL = "{USER}/{PWD}@{SERVER}:{PORT}/{SERVICE}".format(USER=O_USER,
                                                            PWD=O_PWD,
                                                            SERVER=O_SERVER,
                                                            PORT=O_PORT,
                                                            SERVICE=O_SERVICE
                                                           )

try:
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(OracleURL)
except Exception as MSG:
    exit(33)
```

The problem is, from a security point of view, I do not know how to securely store my password. 
As test version, I put the password in a parameter file, encoded in 64bit (which is incredibly low security level). Do you have any good method to store and use the password efficiently ?

Comment: I found that the easiest way is to prompt user to use his credentials so I don't have to store anything when connecting to DB. But that will only work if the script interacts with the user. Otherwise I'll usually create new user for the script with very restricted privileges. But I know that this is not really a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen users pass the password in environment variables.

But you might want to look at using an Oracle "Secure External Password Store".  In summary, you make a 'wallet', add some credentials to it, set up Oracle sqlnet.ora and tnsname.ora files so the wallet is used and then connect to the db service - the SQL*Plus syntax would be `sqlplus -l /@db_connect_string`.  This is described in the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authentication.htm#DBSEG99815).